# Installing Gigatree on Windows 10?

Tags: gedcom, maps

I installed Gigatree on Windows 10, Run shows this error. Cann't find the batchfile the error is referring to, even though the folder should show hidden files.

What should I do to get this program running?

Windows 10 shouldn't be the problem I hope. Maybe my laptop is too well protected to run batch files for security reasons?

[image]

Comment: When you launch Gigatree, try right-clicking and selecting `Run as Administrator`. If this works, the problem is a rights issue (perhaps with the file; perhaps with the folders), and the application doesn't have the rights to run the file when run as a regular user.

Comment: Run as Administrator works! Thanks a lot for your help sempaiscuba.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, make sure you are running Version 4.3.3. According to [a comment that Tim Forsythe](http://gigatrees.appspot.com/blog/gigatrees.html#comment-3648016606), the author of the program, made just 5 days ago on Dec 5, 2017 on his blog post:

> Version 4.3.3 fixes several crashes, endless loops and other types of
>   fatal builds.

If the problem still happens in Version 4.3.3, you should contact the author directly. The best way might be to reply to the comment where Tim mentions the 4.3.3 fixes.